# CakePHP 2.x not treating a string as a string

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In a controller method I have the following code:

```
$this->loadModel('Navigation');
$this->Navigation->updateAll(array('Navigation.name' => $this->request->data['Tag']['name']), array('Navigation.tag_id' => $this->request->data['Tag']['id']));
```

It's producing the following error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ' 
Germany' in 'field list'

SQL Query: UPDATE `dev_hub_subdb_v5_interface`.`navigations` AS 
`Navigation` SET `Navigation`.`name` = Germany WHERE 
`Navigation`.`tag_id` = 3
```

The reason appears to be that it's not treating "Germany" as a string when trying to write it to a column called `name` which is a `varchar(255)` field in MySQL.

However, the data is in string format. If I `var_dump` the request data that's about to be saved, I get this:

```
array(2) { ["Save"]=> string(6) "Update" ["Tag"]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["name"]=> string(7) "Germany" } }
```

Why doesn't this work? According to the [documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-mixed-conditions) `updateAll` accepts 2 arrays: the data to be saved and the conditions. So I can't see how else to write this.

Comment: You may want to closely re-read the docs that you've linked.

Comment: Thanks @ndm I've got it now. The example they've given looks confusing to me but quoting the strings does seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

So it appears to be the case that you have to quote strings, even if they are strings...

The documentation I referred to above has a rather poor explanation/example but says:

> The `$fields` array accepts SQL expressions. Literal values should be quoted manually using `DboSource::value()`. For example if one of your model methods was calling `updateAll()` you would do the following:

```
$db = $this->getDataSource();
$value = $db->value($value, 'string');
$this->updateAll(
    array('Baker.status' => $value),
    array('Baker.status' => 'old')
);
```

I've no idea what that example means as they appear to be updating `Baker.status` twice, with strings. Clear as mud!

Anyway, in my case, adding a quote around `$this->request->data['Tag']['name']` fixed it:

```
$this->Navigation->updateAll(array('name' => "'".$this->request->data['Tag']['name']."'"), array('tag_id' => $this->request->data['Tag']['id']));
```

Comment: The example doesn't update the status twice, it updates the status where the status currently has the value `old`. The example demonstrates how to quote the the value that you want to set, as that doesn't happen by default, unlike when using `key => value` notation with the `save()` method. Do not manually add quotes around the value if it's user data, that isn't safe against SQL injections!, instead use the `DboSource::value()` method as shown in the example, which applies the same quoting that is used in the saving process (`PDO::quote()`).

Comment: I had a go at trying to explain Cake's `updateAll` method a couple of year's ago if it helps: [Use CakePHP 2's updateAll() Method with Caution!](http://andy-carter.com/blog/use-cakephp-2-s-updateall-method-with-caution).

Comment: Thanks @drmonkeyninja that's really useful. Having said that I don't really know what the point of `updateAll()` is if you can use `save()` etc... Seems to add a layer of complexity for no real benefit?

Comment: It depends on the data, `updateAll()` is very useful when updating larger datasets, let's say for example 10.000 records, as it has only little PHP wise overhead (update process is only invoked once, no validation, no existence checks, no callbacks, etc), and only issues a single SQL `UPDATE` query, where as `save/Many()` has lots of overhead on the PHP side, especially because the whole saving process needs to be invoked individually for every single record, also resulting in at least 1 SQL query being issued for each record.